# Controlling video playback (play, pause, forward, seekbar) on BlackBerry

Tags: user-interface, video, blackberry, java-me, mmapi

Can anyone please help me to add video controls (play, pause, forward, seekbar) to my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Player.stop()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#stop%28%29), [Player.start()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#start%28%29) for play and pause
use [FramePositioningControl](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/media/control/FramePositioningControl.html) for forward and seekbar